# Растяжение сторон прямоугольника

Tags: winapi, delphi

Мне нужно нарисовать произвольный прямоугольник и реализовать его растяжения, т.е. щёлкнули мышью по одной стороне, переместили курсор и сторона потялась за ним. Программу написал, но она работает, только если окно с рисунком полностью развернуть, знаю в чем ошибка (несоответствие координат рабочей области и экрана), но не могу никак исправить. Помогите, пожалуйста.

```
program Win1;

uses
  Windows,
  Messages;

var
  WndClass: TWndClass;
  szAppName: PChar;
  WinHandle: HWnd;
  Msg: TMsg;
  Pen: HPen;
  x1,y1,x2,y2: Integer;
  b1,b2,b3,b4,i,k,k1,i1: Integer;
  a1:Integer=100;
  a2:Integer=100;
  a3:Integer=550;
  a4:Integer=300;

function MyWndProc (hWnd: HWND; Msg: UINT; wParam:WPARAM;
  lParam: LPARAM) : LRESULT; stdcall;

var
  ps: TPaintStruct;
  Context: HDC;
  Font: HFont;
 gpoint: tpoint;

begin
case Msg of
 WM_MOUSEMOVE :
   begin  // Перемещаем левую сторону
     if  k=1
       then begin
         if  (wParam= MK_LBUTTON)
           then begin
                  Context := GetDC (hWnd) ;
                  GetCursorPos(gpoint);

                  x2 := gpoint.x;
                  y2 := gpoint.y;SelectObject (Context, GetStockObject (WHITE_PEN));
                    if x1<a3
                      then Rectangle(Context, a1+b1-5, a2, a3, a4)
                      else Rectangle(Context, a1+b1+5, a2, a3, a4);
                       b1:=x2-x1;
                       b2:=y2-y1;
                      SelectObject (Context, GetStockObject (BLACK_PEN)) ;
                      Rectangle(Context, a1+b1, a2, a3, a4);
                end;
             ReleaseDC (hWnd, context) ;
             result:= 0;
           end;

    .............. и.д. (правую, верхнюю, нижнюю)

  WM_PAINT:
    begin

      Context := BeginPaint(hWnd, ps);
      try
        SelectObject(Context, Pen);
        Rectangle(Context, a1, a2, a3, a4);
      finally
        EndPaint(hWnd, ps);
        Result := 0;
      end;
    end;

 WM_LBUTTONDOWN : // захватываем левую сторону
    begin
      SetCapture(hwnd);
      GetCursorPos(gpoint);
     x1 := gpoint.x;
     y1 := gpoint.y;   
         if a2<a4
            then begin
                 if  (x1>(a1-5)) and (x1<a1+5) and (y1>(a2+5))  and (y1<(a4-5))
                   then k:=1;
                 end;
                 //if x1= pt[0].x
                 //then k:=1;

          if a2>a4
            then begin
                   if  (x1>(a1-5)) and (x1<(a1+5)) and (y1<(a2-5))  and (y1>(a4+5))
                     then k:=1;
                 end;  (и.д. ............)
 WM_LBUTTONUP :
    begin
      ReleaseCapture();
      k:=0;
      k1:=0;
      i:=0;
      i1:=0;
        if  (x1>(a1-5)) and (x1<(a1+5)) and (y1>(a2+5)) and (y1<(a4-5))
             or  (x1>(a1-5)) and (x1<(a1+5)) and (y1<(a2-5))  and (y1>(a4+5))
          then a1:=a1+b1;
(.................)

создаём окно...........
```

Answer (score 4):

Меня лично пугают вещи вроде `(x1 > a1 - 5) and (y1 < a2 - 5)`, поэтому опишу способ, как бы я решал данную задачу.

---

У вас есть некоторый прямоугольник, который задается 4 параметрами - `x, y, width, height`, и, очевидно, есть объект *(или просто набор переменных)*, где эти значения хранятся.

Вам нужно понять, какой именно параметр менять в зависимости от того, где был сделан щелчок кнопкой мыши, для сохранения этого следует использовать аналог `enum` в `Delphi`:

```
type
  TRectangleChangingDirection = (ChangingX, ChangingY, ChangingWidth, ChangingHeight);
```

**Дальше последовательность действий очевидна:**

- **`WM_LBUTTONDOWN:`** Определить, какой именно параметр прямоугольника будет изменяться и записать это значение в переменную типа `TRectangleChangingDirection`. Также изначальное положение курсора, т.к именно от него будет отсчитываться изменение параметров прямоугольника, назовем эту переменную `rectangleChangeStartCursorPosition`.
- **`WM_MOUSEMOVE:`** Получить вектор `cursorDifference = currentPosition - rectangleChangeStartCursorPosition`. Из него, в зависимости от изменяемого параметра в прямоугольнике взять координату `x` или `y` и прибавить ее к этому самому изменяемому параметру прямоугольника. **В зависимости от желаемого поведения, здесь можно, например, поставить ограничения, что, скажем, прямоугольник не может иметь отрицательную ширину и т.п.** Записать измененное значение в параметры прямоугольника.
- **`WM_BUTTONUP:`** Ничего делать не нужно, т.к изменения уже были записаны в параметры прямоугольника.
- **`WM_PAINT:`** Отрисовать прямоугольник по текущим сохраненным параметрам.

---

Если вы, например, хотите допустить возможность отменять изменения прямоугольника *(скажем, по кнопке `ESC`)*, то необходимо создавать 2 набора параметров `(x, y, width, height)` - до начала изменения и во время изменения и, в зависимости от действия пользователя, применять изменения или, наоборот, откатывать их к изначальному состоянию. *Получается такое тривиальное применение `Transaction Pattern` с соответствующим `rollback'ом`.*